# Клиент IMAP работающий через прокси

Tags: c#, imap

Доброго времени суток, сейчас нахожусь в поисках IMAP клиента, который бы поддерживал работу через прокси и был бесплатным. Гугл достаточно давал мне библиотек, которые поддерживали прокси, но все они платные, нет ли бесплатных библиотек ? на подобии  imapx или AE.Net.Mail

Comment: Вам библиотека нужна поддерживающая IMAP?

Comment: библиотека, которая поддерживает imap + поддерживает работу с прокси, но при этом является бесплатной